# RegExp to match a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I am using an autocomplete box within an HTML form.

where "val" contains the contents of the text field:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
     if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) 
     {
     ...code to create drop down list...
     }

}
```

But this only works with matching patterns from the start.  Would like to use RegEx instead to select any array items that contain val anywhere in the array.

I have tried

```
var results = arr[i].match(/val/i);
if (var)…
```

But obviously that has failed.

Obviously I could modify the second if statement to loop through the entire length of the array variable, but that would be a waste of time.

Can someone help me with the current usuage?

Comment: can you show us input and expected output, to me it's not so clear as the regex you have written should work. even though it will match only one instance

Comment: `var results = arr[i].match(new RegExp(val, 'i'));`

Comment: @ponury-kostek, hopefully `val` doesn't contain any regular expressions metacharacters

Comment: @ponury-kostek Is it possible that `var results = arr[i].match(new RegExp(val, 'i'));` only matches at the beginning of the string? I need it to match anywhere.

Comment: @DanielKaplan yes it will match anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through your array with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the unwanted elements. Using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to dynamically create a regex from a given value.

```
var regex = new RegExp(val, 'i');

arr.filter(str => str.match(regex))
   .forEach(str => {
     // everything here matches the regex
     // ... code to create drop down list ...
   });
```

Note that this does allow the user to also type regex in the input box. If you want to take their input literal you'll have to [escape the special regex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex).

Alternatively you could also use the [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method if you are searching for a literal match.

```
var upVal = val.toUpperCase();
arr.filter(str => str.toUpperCase().includes(upVal));
```

If your `arr` is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) convert it to an array first using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Comment: I've assigned `new RegExp(val, 'i')` to a variable to avoid re-instantiating the same regex inside the `.filter` loop. eg. `.filter(item => item.match(new RegExp(val, 'i')))` will instantiate a new regex for every item you're trying to match.

Comment: Thanks for this, I believe it is the best way. but within each loop how do I get the full string?  Is it part of item?

Comment: @DanielKaplan `item` is the string, I'll update the answer to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about Internet Explorer (or if you do and use polyfills), there's the `String.prototype.includes` method. So simply

```
if arr[i].toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase()) //...
```